# Maven property with source's VCS root?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Is there a Maven property with root of the VCS? I.e., the parent directory of `.git` or `.hg` directory?

I need to extract Java 8 JRE binaries that I use for tests. It works to use `${session.executionRootDirectory}` during build on Jenkins and I get the JRE only once and I can use it everywhere. But if I manually run a subproject, I get another copy of the JRE extracted.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand the relationship between Git and JRE part? Can you give an example and what the real problem is?

Comment: @khmarbaise Java 8 JRE is required for some tests. I get it via Dependency Maven plugin. I extract it at `${session.executionRootDirectory}/target`. But the `executionRootDirectory` depends on where you start the `mvn` command. Being able to detect the `.git` directory parent directory would allow me to extract it only once regardless of where I start the `mvn` command.

Comment: Use JDK9+ and define `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>` within the module where you need JDK8 code.

Comment: @khmarbaise No. I need it for the tests, not for compilation.

Comment: Where is the difference? please make an example project on GitHub or alike... and show the setup and what the real problem is...You can also define the source/target only for the testing part...

Comment: @khmarbaise The difference is that I am running Maven with Java 11 but I need Java 8 for the tests. The reason I need Java 8 for the tests is that some libraries do not like Java 11, like the version of JMockit that have here. And no, I cannot easily upgrade JMockit.

Comment: So first why not using JDK8 as well for running Maven and Tests etc. Why using JMockit...if it blocks upgrading to JDK11...is time to say good bye...

Answer (score 0):

There is a "[maven git plugin](https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin)" that gives some information over the commit. And this plugin has a property for specifying where is the .git directory:

```
<dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
```

In your case, you have a multi-module structure. If you access this property in one of your sub-modules it will give you the base dir of the sub-project instead of the "parent" (unless you use absolute paths).

You can create a property in each sub-module to do the same thing (assuming that *.git* is in your parent module):

```
  <properties>
    <vcs.root.path>${basedir}/../.git
    </vcs.root.path>
  </properties>
```